# How to index div tag with same ID on HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Let say, I have code as follow

```
<div id='tes' data-name='baloon'>Content Baloon</div>
<div id='tes' data-name='big'>Content Big</div>
```

And I want to get inner of each div with javascript (not jquery) but work on html5. How to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have elements with the same ID in an HTML (5 or any other version) document - it is an error. Therefore, there is no way javascript can address this.

Check the HTML spect at http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

You can have multiple elements with the same "name" property - and javascript offers support for that.

Comment: Interestingly, `querySelectorAll('[id="something"]')` has no problem finding multiple matches: http://jsfiddle.net/4VtqP/1/

Comment: The statement that you cannot have multiple elements with the same id is not strictly true,as the OP has found. Conceptually handling them is not a problem. But getElementById is defined as returning a single DOM node, very reasonably based on the specification stating that id's SHOULD be unique.

Comment: @HBP: You apparently do not understand a more general point. If you follow the specification then your code in a compliant browser must work. If it's not in the specs then may be will work (for any definition of work you may like) may be will not, may be will work only on tuesdays. Whatever bad happens is your fault.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `tes` a class and use Javascript to fetch all `div` elements with the class.

Then iterate through that set of elements and check for the specific `data-name` attribute you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

Every div tag "class" or "id" cannot have same specific name.

data-name is use to match javascript function nor command given.